# How can I change the ui->widget->windowOpacity?

Tags: qt, qt4

Now I want to change the ui->widget->windowOpacity and ui->stackedWidget->windowOpacity() ,but failed.

```
void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   QTimer *timerOpacity = new QTimer(this);
   connect(timerOpacity,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(changeOpacity()));
   timerOpacity->start(100);
}

void Widget::changeOpacity()
{
    if (opalevel > 8) return;

    double opacity[9] =  {0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1};

    ui->stackedWidget->setWindowOpacity(opacity[opalevel]);
    ui->widget->setWindowOpacity(opacity[opalevel]);
    this->setWindowOpacity(opacity[opalevel]);

    qDebug()<<"opalevel = "<< opalevel <<" ui->widget opacity:"<<ui->widget->windowOpacity();
    qDebug()<<"opalevel = "<< opalevel <<" ui->stackedWidget opacity:"<<ui->stackedWidget->windowOpacity();
    qDebug()<<"opalevel = "<< opalevel <<" ui opacity : "<< this->windowOpacity()<<endl;

    opalevel++;
}
```

Debug log :

```
opalevel =  0  ui->widget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  0  ui->stackedWidget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  0  ui opacity:  0.898039 

opalevel =  1  ui->widget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  1  ui->stackedWidget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  1  ui opacity:  0.8 

opalevel =  2  ui->widget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  2  ui->stackedWidget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  2  ui opacity:  0.698039 

opalevel =  3  ui->widget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  3  ui->stackedWidget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  3  ui opacity:  0.596078 

opalevel =  4  ui->widget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  4  ui->stackedWidget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  4  ui opacity:  0.498039 

opalevel =  5  ui->widget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  5  ui->stackedWidget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  5  ui opacity:  0.4 

opalevel =  6  ui->widget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  6  ui->stackedWidget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  6  ui opacity:  0.298039 

opalevel =  7  ui->widget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  7  ui->stackedWidget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  7  ui opacity:  0.2 

opalevel =  8  ui->widget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  8  ui->stackedWidget opacity: 1 
opalevel =  8  ui opacity:  0.0980392
```

Thank you for your help .

Comment: I'd love to help, but since you're using ui I assume you have a desiger created dialog? At least describe how your widgets are organized in this dialog.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I used Qt Creator to create a UI file, and drag UI components . Using dialog  is OK, but the widget not.I get the reason :                                                         void QWidget::setWindowOpacity(qreal opacity)
{
    Q_D(QWidget);
    if (!isWindow())
        return;
//...

Comment: It's not a window.So...  How can I change the opacity of widget which is added to a main widget (window) ?  Thanks  ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`QGraphicsOpacityEffect`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html) on your non-top-level widgets:

```
// in the constructor
opacityEffect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect;
ui->widget->setGraphicsEffect(opacityEffect);
...
// in changeOpacity()
opacityEffect->setOpacity(opacity[opalevel]);
```